# how to addreference to Ritmo for iSeries in ironpython

Tags: c#, ironpython

I was just wondering if anybody knows how to add reference to "Ritmo for iSeries" in IronPython.
I did it successfully in C# and get it to work (since it is just click click click) And I was trying to do the same in IronPython but it says, "could not add reference to assembly Ritmo for iSeries".

I was doing

import clr
clr.AddReference('Ritmo for iSeries')
from Ritmo........

IOError: Could not add reference to assembly Ritmo for iSeries

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the actual name of the assembly (it won't have spaces).

In your C# project, what does it list under the 'references' folder once you've added it as a reference?  Try putting that.  Also, make sure you've copied the dll for the library to where your IronPython script can find it (if it's not in the GAC).

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan helped me to figure out that I had not copied the dll file to the location where IronPython can find it.

After copying the dll file to the location, usually it s "c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.0\"
unless stated otherwise, I did:

import clr

clr.AddReference('System.Data')

clr.AddReferenceToFile('Sql400.dll')

from System.Data import Sql400

from System.Data.Sql400 import *